# TFS 2018 Logs getting to big

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am working with TFS 2018 for some time.
My log files are growing up.
TFS_DefaultCollection_log is 33 GB, TFS_Configuration_log is about 1GB, TFS_Reporting_log is 663 MB and ReportServer_log is about 73 MB (for example). You can see it in the attachment.

How can I solve this? Can I delete those log files (TFS_DefaultCollection_log, TFS_Configuration_log, TFS_Reporting_log) directly from the file explorer?

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. You need to look into your SQL backup strategy.

Comment: I'd already read that. I am not new in this community. I believe my question is clear but If you don't understand what I've asked I may explain better...

Comment: So can anyone help me with this please? How can I shrink the log files size?

Comment: This is a SQL Server question, not one about TFS. Reconsider your backup strategy.

Comment: Ok. I've found out that in Server Management Studio I have an option to shrink Files or Database. Do you think that I can use it to shrink the log files I want? If I do this will I loose any import data from my collections/projects?